# Is there a solution for page-break-inside not working on safari print?

Tags: css, printing, safari, webkit

For a long time now, I'm looking for a solution for that page-break-inside problem on Safari (testing on V5 here). I've read a dozen pages full of arguing about whether it works or not. Still, for me it doesn't work. My Element (which I'm trying to prevent from breaking when printing) comes with the following css-styles:

```
position: absolute;
opacity: 1;
float: left;
display: block;
```

Could it have something to do with position:absolute;?

[You can see the Page here.](http://ammarkt.ch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp

"You cannot use this property on absolutely positioned elements."